# Which Maruts incarnated as Satyaki, Kritavarma, Virata, and Drupada?

Tags: mahabharata, avatars, maruts

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01068.htm

> And he who was Satyaki of sure aim, that upholder of the pride of Vrishni race, that oppressor of foes, begotten of the portion of gods called the Maruts. And that royal sage Drupada who on earth was a monarch, the first among all persons bearing arms, was also born of the same tribe of the celestials. And, O king, thou shouldst also know that Kritavarman, that prince among men, of deeds unsurpassed by any one, and the foremost of all bulls amongst Kshatriyas, was born of the portion of the same celestials. And that royal sage also, Virata by name, the scorcher of the kingdoms of others, and the great oppressor of all foes, was born of the portion of the same gods.

Which Maruts gods' portions Satyaki, Kritavarma, Virata, and Drupada were of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am providing only a partial answer here regarding Drupada. The Devi Bhagavatam mentions Drupada to be an incarnation of Varuna.

> 35. S’antanu was the part incarnate of the Ocean; his wife, of the river Ganges in human farm. It is stated in the Purânas that the king
>     Devaka was part incarnate of the Lord of Gandarvas. 36-41. The
>     Grand-father of the Kauravas, the foremost of the heroes, Bhîsma Deva
>     was the incarnate of Vasu; Virâta, the Lord of Matsya was the part
>     incarnate of Maruts; Dhritarâstra, of the Daitya Hamsa, the son of
>     Arista Nemi; Kripa and Krita Varmâ, of Maruts; Duryodhana, of Kali and
>     S’akuni, of Dvâpara; Suvarchâkhya Somapraru, of the son of the Moon;
>     Dhristadyumna was part incarnate of Fire and S’ikhandî of Râksasa;
>     Pradyumna was part incarnate of Sanatkumâra; **the king Drupada was
>     part incarnate of Varuna**; Draupadî, of Laksmî; Draupadî’s five sons,
>     of Visve-devas; Kuntî was incarnate of Siddhi; Mâdri, of Dhriti;
>     Gândhârî, of Mati; the wives of S’rî Krisna were the heavenly public
>     women; thus all the Devas came as their part incarnations, urged on by
>     Indra. 42-43. Amongst the Asuras, S’is’upâla was the incarnate of
>     Hiranyakas’ipu; Jarâsandha, of Biprachitti, S’alya, of Prahlâda;
>     Kamsa, of Kâlanemi and Kes’î, of Haya S’irâ. The Asura named Arista of
>     the form of a cow that was killed by Krisna was the son of Bali
>
> *Devi Bhagavatam; Chapter 22; Book 4*